# Javascript AES with Initialization Vector

Tags: javascript, aes

I need a javascript library which can decrypt AES data. I've found some libraries, like:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html

http://point-at-infinity.org/jsaes/

But none of them support a IV key (Initialization Vector).

The reason i need that is because some C#.NET server is sending me data which is encrypted with AES and it also uses a IV key.

Now i need to decrypt that message with Javascript somehow, but couldn't find any library which supports the Initialization Vector. So does anyone know a javascript library which supports this too for decrypting?

Answer (score 1):

The IV is not strictly a feature of AES. It depends on the mode of operation. The first link only implements CTR mode, and the second doesn't use any mode (it just encrypts one block).
You should check what mode is used by your server.
If it is CBC, you should be able to implement it over an AES implementation without any problem.

And now for the fun question: why do you have a server encrypting data to send it to JS? It doesn't add any security: JS is always executed in an unsafe environment (cf http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/ for more information).

Comment: Eventough its not 100% secure, it does add some security. The packets are not readable when you sniff with a packetsniffer. So i thought its better to have some security then none at all.

Comment: If someone is motivated enough to sniff your packets, he will be able to get the encrypted packet along with the key. And if the key is generated from user input, he may also be able to inject something in the page to get the key (or simply get directly the decrypted content). Breaking your JS crypto may be harder than no security, but not by much. If you want to secure your content, use SSL.

Comment: He could be running Javacsript on his server using node.js